# C# assign an event to a "group" of controls?

Tags: c#, events, grouping, mouseevent

I have a big numbers of labels custom controls let's say 100.
I would like to give them an MouseHover event.
I could do something like:

```
private void label_custom1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox.Text = label_custom1.backcolor.ToString();
        }
```

But then I would need to do that 100 times. Since I have 100 of them.
Is there a way to do that only once?
I guess I should probably declare the function in my custom_label class but so far I couldn't make it work.
Any Idea how to proceed?

Comment: are adding labels at runtime?

Comment: I added labels manually using Visual Studio designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, create a common event, we receive the Label posted here.

```
private void Common_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox.Text = (sender as Label).BackColor.ToString();
}
```

Give the common event to all Labels on the form. Here I assume Label names start with `label`, for example `label1`, `label2`, `label3` ...

```
private void SetEventAllLabels()
{
    var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("label"));
    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
        label.MouseHover += Common_MouseHover;
    }
}
```

Call the SetEventAllLabels () method in the Load method of the form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetEventAllLabels();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create only one event handler method like this:

```
private void Label_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox.Text = (sender as Label).BackColor.ToString();
}
```

And subscribe all Events to that method:

```
 this.label_custom1.MouseHover += Label_MouseHover;
 this.label_custom2.MouseHover += Label_MouseHover;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this was very helpful.

This part didnt work though, it couldnt recognize the controls:

```
private void SetEventAllLabels()
{
    var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("label"));
    foreach (var label in labels)
    {
        label.MouseHover += Common_MouseHover;
    }
}
```

So I create a list containing all the label names and Then it works using this:

```
foreach (string i in liste)
            {
                CustomLabel x = (CustomLabel)(this.Controls.Find(i, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label);
                x.MouseEnter += Common_MouseHover;

             }
```

As a side note, using MouseEnter instead of MouseHover makes it much more responsive (faster reaction!)

Comment: Glad it helps. You said it didn't recognize Controls, which framework did you work with? Actually, the Control class uses the "System.Windows.Forms" namespace, just like the Label class